# Two different jQuery functions in the same HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a HTML page and I want to use jQuery for my slide-show and pop-out image (The jQuery-lightbox) on a same page. However, when I active these two function at the same time, the pop-out image function works, but the slide-show section stopped working. Maybe I wrote the function in a wrong way....

I appreciate your help!

Here is my code:

```
<head>
<!--slideshow-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#slider').nivoSlider({

        effect:'random',

    });
});
</script>

<!--Lighbox-popout-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#photo a').lightBox();
});
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

you're loading two different versions of jquery that are interfering with each other. get rid of this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `window.load` use `$(function() { ... })`. Also, the DOM isn't ready when your are calling for lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

You're including 2 versions of jQuery it seems, disable one or the other and see if will work then.

Also, lose the trailing comma in the line `effect:'random',`, some browser will choke on that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<head>
<!--slideshow-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Lighbox-popout-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#photo a').lightBox();
              $('#slider').nivoSlider({effect:'random'});
});
</script>
</head>
```